# Python error in reading config parameter

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, configparser, gspread

I am trying to read Google Spreadsheet, using the **gspread** module. I have some config parameters in the config.ini. I have successfully read all the config except **scope** parameter.

Original value:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
```

When I read this parameter through configparser, it is considered as string.
I want to include in OAuth of the Google Spreadsheet API. If I directly put scope variable into statement it will load without any error, but I want to read it through config file.

> Error : HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_scope: ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'] is not a valid audience string.

I tried the solution by converting string into list but no solution.

Comment: Try converting your list to a space separated string by doing: `' '.join(scope)`. In your case, that a simple string containing 1 item, `'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'`
OAuth 2.0 scopes must be represented that way, according to the standard: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#page-23

Comment: it worked. Thanks